# How can I use mod_rewrite to prevent access from clients, but not from server?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

My web app assigns a user account based on URL entered. It should behave something like [notepad.cc](http://notepad.cc) where each unique URI is a different notepad.

But if user enteres a file that exists on my server, I do not want user to see the contents of the file. It seems simple, but I have been unable to achieve this. I know I can use mod_rewrite to prevent access to files, but as soon as I do this, server can't also access them.

For example, if I have a file called `foo` and when user enters `www.mysite.com/foo`, I do not want to show the contents of the file, but instead redirect to an index.html and generate a new account or load the account if it already exists.

How can I do this with mod_rewrite?

**EDIT: I tried using an IP whitelist as suggested, but this did not work either.**

This is what I have so far.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.1\.4$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.html [L]
```

Everything is redirected to index.html whether the URI entered points an existing file or not. However, css and js files that are necessary for index.html are not loaded even when testing on 192.168.1.4.

Comment: So, urls like `www.example.com/css/style.css` shouldn't be accessible too? The most obvious answers are (1) either don't _have_ anything which shouldn't be accessible in your document root, or (2) filter on whitelisted ips (127.0.0.1, server's own local and/or public ip, etc.).

Comment: @Wrikken That is correct. I don't want css/style.css to be directly accesible from users. I thought about using the IP as a filter. I can give that a try.

Comment: @Wrikken Tried it, but didn't work, either. Please see my edit.

Comment: You have conflicting requirements: _". I don't want css/style.css to be directly accesible from users"_ and _"css and js files that are necessary for index.html"_... choose one or the other.

Comment: True, and I was asking to accomplish both of them. So it seems that there is no way to achieve this?

Comment: Problem is, js-files, stylesheets, images, etc. always are direct separate requests, and you can't trust the `Referer` header.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you problem correctly but wouldn't this help:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.1\.4$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.1\.4$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.html [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, but this did not work. What I want to do is I do not want users to access files directly but allow the server to access them because index.html needs to use css and js files on the server.